# rdl report Filter sums

Tags: filter, sum, reportbuilder, rdl

How can i write the expression in rdl report for the following :

```
Sum(Fields!Amount.Value) where AccountType='Income' - SUM(Fields!Amount.Value) where AccountType='Cost of Goods Sold')
```

Am Using only 1 dataset with the following columns `AccountType` `AccountName` `Amount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is any other way but this is the only way I found .

create 2 variables in the rdl report .

e.g

1st variable **IncomeTotal**  I set the expression to

```
=SUM(iif(Fields!AccountType.Value="Income",CDbl(Fields!Amount.Value),CDbl(0.00)),"YourDatasetName")
```

2nd variable **CostOfGoodsSoldTotal** I set the expression to

```
=SUM(iif(Fields!AccountType.Value="Cost of Goods Sold",CDbl(Fields!Amount.Value),CDbl(0.00)),"YourDatasetName")
```

And then I subtract the 2 variables where appropriate  with the following expression

```
=Variables!IncomeTotal.Value - Variables!CostOfGoodsSoldTotal.Value
```